# rails share coffeescript between multiple pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to understand why this sometimes works. I have a file called `shared.coffee` with this code

```
@sharedSearchButton = ->
  $('#button_search_box').click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $('#search_box').toggle()
    return
  return
$(document).ready(sharedSearchButton)
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', sharedSearchButton)
```

I import this file in `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require shared
//= require_tree .
```

If I click on a link that redirects me to one of the pages where this code has to work, it works just fine. On the other hand, if I reload the page it does not work.

---

**UPDATE**

I found that if I put

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', sharedSearchButton)
```

It works for the link_to buttons that I have on other pages, but not when I refresh the page. On the contrary, if I write

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:change', sharedSearchButton)
```

It works when I refresh the page but not when I come from a link_to

Comment: You don't need to ```//= require shared``` because ```//= require_tree .```  directive tells Sprockets to recursively include all JavaScript files in the specified directory into the output. Can you inspect your page to make sure you have your ```shared.coffee``` code in Sources

Comment: Thank you @MaverickTan you are right, I do not need to add `//= require shared`. I inspected the code, and it always appears.I will update de question because I find something more.